# About docker storage

Tags: docker

So, I've recently found out about docker. I want to run https://toshi.io , however, it takes 800GB (I think) to have a blockchain. Storage is no problem, I have other large hard drive but not so much in my main ubuntu installation (I have only 11GB free on root).

I see that docker stores its stuff (and I guess app state) in the /var/ somewhere.

How do I tell docker to use so and so folder on a mounted hard drive so I would not run out of disk space?

More than that, If I took that hard drive which will contain all those 800GB of blockchain data and put it in a new machine would I be able to just run docker on a new machine and the app wouldn't see a difference and would just run as if it was not moved?

Comment: You probably want to start with [this document](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I needed to use postgres dockerhub image and simply run it with

```
docker run --name toshi_db -v <my desired host directory>:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres
```

And toshi does not care where to store blockchain data as it simply uses the address for database.